# increment the view counter while fetching in one single query laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table named `advertisments` which has `views` column.
I want to fetch the data from `advertisments` table and increment each row's `views` in a single query is it possible ?.

The following code is what I wrote to achieve the desired result but the `views` aren't updating.

```
Advertisement::with('sponsor')
            ->whereDeleted(false)
            ->whereHeader(false)
            ->orderBy('views')
            ->raw("update views ".DB::raw('views + 1'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: Just write two separate queries. It is more readable for anyone.

Comment: @u_mulder There's a reason why I want to achieve it with one query, I need to lesser backend queries as much as possible the server is really old so I need to do the best I can.

Comment: This will improve __nothing__.

Comment: @u_mulder processing time. there will be many results, I can't map throught all of them and increment the queries.

Comment: If 1 single extra query is causing that much of a performance issue, then the issue is elsewhere, not with the single extra query.

Comment: If I could do it in one single query it'll save me loads of queries, mapping though multiple result and then updating them won't be a good solution. @Ohgodwhy